# Unexpected benchmark results

Tags: go

Given this code:

```
// Code A
//go:noinline
func find_max1(arr []int) (resp1 int, resp2 int) {
        max := 0
        maxIndex := 0
        for i := 0; i < len(arr); i++ {
                if max < arr[i] {
                        max = arr[i]
                        maxIndex = i
                }
        }
        return max, maxIndex
}


// Code B
//go:noinline
func find_max2(arr []int) (resp1 int, resp2 int) {
        max := 0
        maxIndex := 0
        for i := 0; i < len(arr); i++ {
                if max >= arr[i] {
                        continue
                }

                max = arr[i]
                maxIndex = i
        }
        return max, maxIndex
}
```

The "arr" is a 100000 int arrays, and I get benchmark results that I don't understand:

```
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
pkg: github.com/test_samples
cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-9880H CPU @ 2.30GHz
BenchmarkFindMax1-12                    6536        181323 ns/op        
BenchmarkFindMax2-12                   20074         59976 ns/op
```

How does it happen that my function `find_max2` is `3` times faster than `find_max1`?

Update#1: add the assembly code analysis here:

```
"".find_max1 STEXT nosplit size=63 args=0x18 locals=0x0 funcid=0x0
        0x0000 00000 (branch_prediction_test.go:35)     TEXT    "".find_max1(SB), NOSPLIT|ABIInternal, $0-24
        0x0000 00000 (branch_prediction_test.go:35)     MOVQ    AX, "".arr+8(FP)
        0x0005 00005 (branch_prediction_test.go:35)     FUNCDATA        $0, gclocals·1a65e721a2ccc325b382662e7ffee780(SB)
        0x0005 00005 (branch_prediction_test.go:35)     FUNCDATA        $1, gclocals·69c1753bd5f81501d95132d08af04464(SB)
        0x0005 00005 (branch_prediction_test.go:35)     FUNCDATA        $5, "".find_max1.arginfo1(SB)
        0x0005 00005 (branch_prediction_test.go:39)     XORL    CX, CX
        0x0007 00007 (branch_prediction_test.go:39)     XORL    DX, DX
        0x0009 00009 (branch_prediction_test.go:39)     XORL    SI, SI
        0x000b 00011 (branch_prediction_test.go:38)     JMP     26
        0x000d 00013 (branch_prediction_test.go:38)     LEAQ    1(DX), R8
        0x0011 00017 (branch_prediction_test.go:45)     MOVQ    DI, DX
        0x0014 00020 (branch_prediction_test.go:45)     MOVQ    CX, SI
        0x0017 00023 (branch_prediction_test.go:38)     MOVQ    R8, CX
        0x001a 00026 (branch_prediction_test.go:38)     CMPQ    BX, CX
        0x001d 00029 (branch_prediction_test.go:38)     JLE     56
        0x001f 00031 (branch_prediction_test.go:39)     MOVQ    (AX)(CX*8), DI
        0x0023 00035 (branch_prediction_test.go:39)     CMPQ    DX, DI
        0x0026 00038 (branch_prediction_test.go:39)     JGE     45
        0x0028 00040 (branch_prediction_test.go:38)     MOVQ    CX, DX
        0x002b 00043 (branch_prediction_test.go:41)     JMP     13
        0x002d 00045 (branch_prediction_test.go:45)     MOVQ    DX, DI
        0x0030 00048 (branch_prediction_test.go:38)     MOVQ    CX, DX
        0x0033 00051 (branch_prediction_test.go:45)     MOVQ    SI, CX
        0x0036 00054 (branch_prediction_test.go:39)     JMP     13
        0x0038 00056 (branch_prediction_test.go:45)     MOVQ    DX, AX
        0x003b 00059 (branch_prediction_test.go:45)     MOVQ    SI, BX
        0x003e 00062 (branch_prediction_test.go:45)     RET
        0x0000 48 89 44 24 08 31 c9 31 d2 31 f6 eb 0d 4c 8d 42  H.D$.1.1.1...L.B
        0x0010 01 48 89 fa 48 89 ce 4c 89 c1 48 39 cb 7e 19 48  .H..H..L..H9.~.H
        0x0020 8b 3c c8 48 39 fa 7d 05 48 89 ca eb e0 48 89 d7  .<.H9.}.H....H..
        0x0030 48 89 ca 48 89 f1 eb d5 48 89 d0 48 89 f3 c3     H..H....H..H...
```

```
"".find_max2 STEXT nosplit size=45 args=0x18 locals=0x0 funcid=0x0
        0x0000 00000 (branch_prediction_test.go:49)     TEXT    "".find_max2(SB), NOSPLIT|ABIInternal, $0-24
        0x0000 00000 (branch_prediction_test.go:49)     MOVQ    AX, "".arr+8(FP)
        0x0005 00005 (branch_prediction_test.go:49)     FUNCDATA        $0, gclocals·1a65e721a2ccc325b382662e7ffee780(SB)
        0x0005 00005 (branch_prediction_test.go:49)     FUNCDATA        $1, gclocals·69c1753bd5f81501d95132d08af04464(SB)
        0x0005 00005 (branch_prediction_test.go:49)     FUNCDATA        $5, "".find_max2.arginfo1(SB)
        0x0005 00005 (branch_prediction_test.go:53)     XORL    CX, CX
        0x0007 00007 (branch_prediction_test.go:53)     XORL    DX, DX
        0x0009 00009 (branch_prediction_test.go:53)     XORL    SI, SI
        0x000b 00011 (branch_prediction_test.go:52)     JMP     16
        0x000d 00013 (branch_prediction_test.go:52)     INCQ    CX
        0x0010 00016 (branch_prediction_test.go:52)     CMPQ    BX, CX
        0x0013 00019 (branch_prediction_test.go:52)     JLE     38
        0x0015 00021 (branch_prediction_test.go:53)     MOVQ    (AX)(CX*8), DI
        0x0019 00025 (branch_prediction_test.go:53)     CMPQ    DX, DI
        0x001c 00028 (branch_prediction_test.go:53)     JGE     13
        0x001e 00030 (branch_prediction_test.go:61)     MOVQ    CX, SI
        0x0021 00033 (branch_prediction_test.go:61)     MOVQ    DI, DX
        0x0024 00036 (branch_prediction_test.go:58)     JMP     13
        0x0026 00038 (branch_prediction_test.go:61)     MOVQ    DX, AX
        0x0029 00041 (branch_prediction_test.go:61)     MOVQ    SI, BX
        0x002c 00044 (branch_prediction_test.go:61)     RET
        0x0000 48 89 44 24 08 31 c9 31 d2 31 f6 eb 03 48 ff c1  H.D$.1.1.1...H..
        0x0010 48 39 cb 7e 11 48 8b 3c c8 48 39 fa 7d ef 48 89  H9.~.H.<.H9.}.H.
        0x0020 ce 48 89 fa eb e7 48 89 d0 48 89 f3 c3           .H....H..H...
```

As we see, find_max1 will cost more registers and instructions than find_max2.

- If max >= arr[i]: find_max1-> 12  find_max2->5
- If max < arr[i]: find_max1-> 9 find_max2->7

Comment: Start by not benchmarking load_data.

Comment: That works, thx. but why the performance exist 3 times diff.

Comment: I don't get why you removed the assembly code dump.

Comment: I have the same question about the benchmark code. It was there. Wrong, but fixable.

Comment: @mh-cbon，thx for updating my question, my English is not good enough. I removed assembly code because too  many code looks messy. The assembly code  tell me that, find_max1 takes 12/9(true/false) instructions more than find_max2 (5/7-true/false). I dont' know why the go compiler generate this kind of code.

Comment: never mind about your english, the question is better with those elements rather than without. The benchmark also, even wrong, it helps to put everyone on the same line.

Comment: consider the Go team prioritize the time spent on the compiler in regard to what they deem the better.

Comment: @mb-cbon, thx, I added the assembly code. And the benchmark result is just for the find_max1 and find_max2 code without calling load_data. And I have tried same logic in C++ with gcc, it's stable and fast like find_max2. I really suspect go compiler is not smart enough

Answer (score -1):

I see that the second function continues if the value is less than the current max value. It is not executing the code that sets a new value for each value in the array, so it accesses the memory much less, thus resulting in faster execution. To see it for yourself, add a print for each continue, this will slow it down, but also show you how often it skips the heavier set code.

Comment: Skelton, thx for your answer. These two functions are totally the same logic, should have  totally the same set-value(access memory) count.